# Child workorder specifications not saving

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am trying to save child workorder specification values and it's not working as intended. Here is what I have been trying to achieve.

I am retrieving list of parent and child workorder together so that flat structure s maintained and filtering the parent workorders to be displayed on My Assigned Workorder view
e.g. Below are the workorders assigned to a particular user for a particular site.
parent WO - 1000 has child wos - 1001, 1002, 1003
parent WO - 2000 has child wos - 2001, 2002

1. Assigned Workorders View shows only 1000 and 2000 workorder.
2. Once you select a workorder then it shows workorder details and the list of Child WO.
3. There is a tab on the workorder detial screen same as Attachment or Tasks or WorkLogs
4. So the flow is select a parent WO -> Opens Workorder Details view -> Click on Child WOs tab -> displays the list of child WOs
   e.g. select 1000 -> click on Child WO tab -> displays 1001, 1002, 1003
5. Select a child WO and it displays it's specification attributes one by one
6. Enter a value for specification attributes and then go back (takes you to Child WO list screen -> go back (takes you to workorder details screen) -> go back (takes you to My Assigned WOrkorders view)
7. Here comes the problem. Select parent WO and then Child WO, all the child workorder specifications are lost.
8. In js file, I am retrieving the workorder and the workorderSpec resource

```js
initialize: function (eventContext) {
       
  var workOrder = eventContext.application.getResource('workOrder').getCurrentRecord();
  
  var identifier = workOrder.get('identifier');
    
  var workorderSpecs = eventContext.application.getResource("workOrder.workOrderSpec");
   }
```

Surprisingly this code works fine for the first time. But the second time 
eventContext.application.getResource("workOrder.workOrderSpec"); returns null even though var workOrder is holding the correct workorder information.

Let me know if you have confusion around the scenario.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar thing. In the object structure I've added a new view on workorder (WOCHILDREN) and I've changed the workorderspec relationship to include all the specs from the WorkOrder and the specs under children. You should be aware that after downloading the specs to your mobile, this relationship is lost (all the specs still reference the original work order).

I then used the eventContext.ui.viewHistory to determine where I was in the app. Then decide if I need the workorderResource currentRecord or the wochildrenResource current record. And get the identifier from that record.

Now you need to use that identifier (workorderid) to filter the list of workorderspecs.

```
var specs = eventContext.application.getResource('workOrder.workOrderSpec');
specs.filter("refobjectid = $1", workorderid);
```

The problem with this approach is that filtering a resource changes the state of that set. Which means that any unsaved changes are lost. Therefor I added an extra check to see of a set was filtered and dirty (ie. changed) and if so save the set.